# MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) computer dies at 40+%

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Within the last few months computer has been dying at 40+%

After dying the computer will show the low battery icon on the screen, but once charger is plugged in it shows the battery has well over the % at which the laptop should be shutting off.

This usually happens after a restart or opening the computer.  It will turn on, I sign in then it dies shortly thereafter.

Any thoughts?  From what I have read battery re-calibration should not be needed on this particular model.  Have read some bits about it being possible software issues but not sure the real cause.

Comment: How many cycles does the battery have? (About this Mac -> more information -> battery)

Comment: I flagged as a dupe because while there are very minor differences between the two models of MacBook Pro, the symptoms and answer are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  The battery has a bad cell.  Have it replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Marc Wilson may be correct, but another thing to try since it's quick to do is to reset the SMC.

Since your MacBook Pro has a built-in battery, here’s what you do:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (or power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.